# Keyboard shortcuts to control WinAmp

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, winamp

Some keyboards have a play/pause button built into the keyboard. I don't have one of those, but I'd like to set up a keyboard shortcut to do the same thing. I'd like the shortcut to work no matter what application has the focus. Is there a way to configure this in WinXP?

Also, I'm using an old version of WinAmp (2.95). I'm not sure if that matters, as I thought these keyboard buttons worked universally somehow (but maybe I'm wrong?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the command line program [Clever](http://www.winamp.com/plugin/clever/58602) you can drive Winamp with command line arguments.  Once you have that working and have figured out which command line arguments you want to use, you can make a windows shortcut with that command line argument and [then assign a keyboard shortcut to that windows shortcut](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Create-keyboard-shortcuts-to-open-programs).

Comment: thanks. after some more searching i managed to find this plugin which lets me assign global shortcuts, and it works with winamp 2.x: http://www.winamp.com/plugin/dimin-hotkeys/79310

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an [AutoHotkey script](http://www.autohotkey.com/). From the [AutoHotkey docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Winamp.htm) here's an example to bind <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+P</kbd> to the pause/unpause command:

```
^!p::
IfWinNotExist ahk_class Winamp v1.x
    return
; Otherwise, the above has set the "last found" window for use below.
ControlSend, ahk_parent, c  ; Pause/Unpause
return
```